# nested class has a static variable?

Tags: java, class, inner-classes

I know that nested class has not had static member,

```
class OuterClass {
     class InnerClass {
      private static int x = 0; // this is error
     }

}
```

But when we declared it with final

```
 class OuterClass {
     class InnerClass {
      private static final int x = 0; // ok
     }
}
```

is it related with the final keyword, because variable can't be changed anymore?
Or is there another reason for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `private static final int x = 0;` is compile time constant.
According java doc,

> Inner classes may not declare static members, unless they are
>   compile-time constant fields

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is mandated by the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3):

> ### 8.1.3. Inner Classes and Enclosing Instances
>
> An inner class is a nested class that is not explicitly or implicitly declared static.
>
> An inner class may be a non-static member class ([§8.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.5)), a local class ([§14.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.3)), or an anonymous class ([§15.9.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.5)). A member class of an interface is implicitly static ([§9.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.5)) so is never considered to be an inner class.
>
> **It is a compile-time error if an inner class declares a static initializer ([§8.7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.7)).**
>
> **It is a compile-time error if an inner class declares a member that is explicitly or implicitly static, unless the member is a constant variable ([§4.12.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4)).**
>
> An inner class may inherit static members that are not constant variables even though it cannot declare them.
>
> A nested class that is not an inner class may declare static members freely, in accordance with the usual rules of the Java programming language.
>
> > Example 8.1.3-1. Inner Class Declarations and Static Members
> >
> > ```
> > class HasStatic {
> >      static int j = 100;
> > }
> > class Outer {
> >     class Inner extends HasStatic {
> >          static final int x = 3;  // OK: constant variable
> >          static int y = 4;  // Compile-time error: an inner class
> >     }
> >     static class NestedButNotInner{
> >         static int z = 5;    // OK: not an inner class
> >     }
> >     interface NeverInner {}  // Interfaces are never inner
> > }
> > ```

Note that this changed with [Java 16](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3):

> All of the rules that apply to nested classes apply to inner classes. In particular, an inner class may declare and inherit `static` members ([§8.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.2)), and declare static initializers ([§8.7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.7)), even though the inner class itself is not `static`.